# Problems using Play template in IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, playframework, scala-template

I'm using Play Framework 2.4 (With Java).
I have a scala template file named `product.scala.html` with a simple checking like this:

```
@if(services.UserService.isAlreadyLogin()) {
  <a href="/link-here">show me</a>
}
```

The code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE (tested on IE 11). The link "`show me`" never displays regardless of the value returned by `isAlreadyLogin()`.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Look at the html generated. If that doesn't contain "show me" then the value returned by isAlreadyLogin isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Templates does not depend on browser. So the issue must be outside of this fragment. Are you sure "services.UserService.isAlreadyLogin()" returns "true" in your test with IE? Maybe cookies are disabled in your IE browser?

Comment: yes, I checked, the isAlreadyLogin() return true on the server. But let me check the cookies stuff